# Python/Django Referencing Nested JSON

Tags: python, json, django, google-maps

I'm using the Google Places Reverse Geocode API to return the latitude and longatude of a given address. The API returns a massive JSON file with tons of nested objects. Here's Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) on it.

I'm trying to grab the geometry.location.lat object (see documentation). Here's my current code, followed by the error it returns:

```
address_coords = gmaps.geocode(raw_address)

# gmaps makes the API request and returns the JSON into address_coords

address_lat = address_coords['results']['geometry']['location']['lat']
address_lon = address_coords['results']['geometry']['location']['lng']
```

> TypeError: List indices must be integers or slices, not str

I'm not sure how to reference that JSON object.

Comment: You should show the data you are trying to access. As the error says, at least one level of that data structure is a list rather than a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that you're trying to index an array as if it were a property.

Most likely `results` is the array, so you'd need to do the following to get the value for the first item at index `0`:

```
address_coords['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
```

The other possibility is that `geometry` contains multiple coordinates which you could similarly index:

```
address_coords['results']['geometry'][0]['location']['lng']
```

Either way, you should pretty print the structure to see which attributes are arrays versus dictionaries.

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(address_coords)
```